# React : Update child component state from parent with asynchronous data

Tags: reactjs

I have a react application where StudentView (parent) needs to update a Table component (child) when the parent fetches the student list asynchronously.

**Parent Component**

```
const StudentView = () => {
    const [studentData, setStudentData] = useState();  

   useEffect(() => {
     let url = "/api/students";
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => {
        setStudentData(response.data);
      })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <Table tableRows={studentData} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default StudentView;
```

**Child Component (Table)**

```
const Table = ({  tableRows }) => {
  
 
  return (
    
      <table className="table table-striped border">
         {createTableBody(tableRows )}
      </table>
    
  );
};

export default Table;
```

The problem is that after the parent fetches the data, the Table is not getting updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) in the child component with the values passed from the parent component

```
const Table = ({  tableRows }) => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(tableRows);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (tableRows) {
      setRows(tableRows);
    }
  }, [tableRows]);

 

  return (
    <table className="table table-striped border">
         {createTableBody(rows)}
      </table>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove the state hook in the child component, the prop tableRows is already a state variable and will trigger the re-render in childs components.

```
const Table = ({  tableRows }) => {

return (
  <table className="table table-striped border">
     {createTableBody(tableRows)}
  </table>
```

Comment: re-render is not working if the data is fetched asynchronously. If the Data is passed when Table is created, then it is working fine.

Comment: asynchronous data is not a problem, this structure should work is the basic principle for Dumb and Smart components: https://coderwall.com/p/znkw-q/smart-vs-dumb-components-when-to-use-which if you tried and didn't work then debug your app because the data is not being updated

Comment: Yes.. I tried, without useEffect and state in the child component, the asynchronous data is not getting updated in the child.

Comment: debug your app because the data is not being updated

Comment: Read this, if you are not convinced. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903577/how-to-pass-async-state-to-child-component-props

Comment: put a console.log(tableRows) in your child component, before the return statement